# Pass 2 parameters into view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got a view where I create new object and pass it to another view:

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,carID,DateFrom,DateTo,UserID")] Reservation reservation)
    {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ChooseCars",reservation);
            }

            return View(reservation);
        }
```

in "ChooseCars" I have:

```
public ActionResult ChooseCars(Reservation reservation)
    {
        var reservations = db.Reservations.ToList();
        var cars = db.Cars.ToList();

        var reservationsResult = reservations.Where(res => res.DateFrom <= reservation.DateFrom && res.DateTo >= reservation.DateTo); 

        if (reservationsResult != null) 
        {
          emptyCars = cars.Where(c => !reservationsResult.Any(y => y.carID == c.ID));  
          cars = emptyCars.ToList();
        }


        return View(cars);
    }
```

and in that "ChooseCars" view I populate table with list of Cars that haven't been reserved.. Now I need to somehow pass that reservation and chosen car (by id) to some method where I create new "reservation" object containing carId.

What is the best way to do that?

I wrote a method, but I have no idea how to route those parameters to it:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AddReservation([Bind(Include = "ID,carID,DateFrom,DateTo,UserID")] Reservation reservation, int? id)
        {
            Reservation finalReservation = new Reservation(id, reservation.DateFrom, reservation.DateTo, reservation.UserID);


            db.Reservations.Add(finalReservation);


            return View();
        }
```

How it looks:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Difficult to understand what your doing here. Why do you POST to `Create()` and then just redirect (instead of submitting direct to the `ChooseCars()` method)? And why are you not just doing this all in one view with one model containing all the information you need (you could use ajax to update the view with the list of available cars based on the dates)

Comment: Im extreme noob in terms of mvc. I need to create website where I can create Cars and Reservations for cars. My thinking was to create 2 models: Car and Reservation. Firstly user choose reservation dates, then he choose available cars in that time, and then create new reservation. Possibly I'm doing everything wrong.

Comment: So the first view is for selecting a range of dates only? And the second displays a list of available cars for those dates? How does the user select a car (or cars) in the view? and what other information does the user need to fill in before saving the `Reservation`?

Comment: Firstly user chooses reservation dates. Then I wanted to pass that dates to another method to see if there are any reservation on those dates and print cars that are not reserved in table. Then I wanted user to choose one of the free cars (buttons in the cars table) and pass it to create new reservation with full information (dateFrom, dateTo, carID).

Comment: There are numerous ways to handle that, and having one view which initially display just the datepickers with a 'Show Cars' button that updates the view with the list of cars using ajax would be the best performance. But if you want to do this without ajax, then you need a different view model (containing just properties for the dates and a collection of the cars). It really depends on the UI you want

Comment: I need the easiest of them. Can you somehow direct me how should I start? Without ajax

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain how you want the UI in the 2nd view to be (e.g. list of cars with associated button that submits the car ID along with the dates?)

Comment: Yup, and after that second image, where is "Wybierz" I want to create that final reservation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your editing data, so the first thing is to create a view model(s) representing want you want to edit/display in the view. In your case you need the start and end dates, a collection of `Car` and the selected car.

```
public class ReservationVM // add validation and display attributes as appropriate
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedCar { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Car> AvailableCars { get; set; }
}
```

And your controller methods will be

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ReservationVM model = new ReservationVM();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ReservationVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    var availableCars = ... // your query to load the collection of cars basd on the dates
    if (!availableCars.Any())
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "There are no cars available for these dates");
        return View(model);
    }
    model.AvailableCars = availableCars;
    return View("SelectCar", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Confirm(ReservationVM model)
{
    // Initialize new Reservation, save and redirect
    Reservation reservation = new Reservation()
    {
        StartDate = model.StartDate,
        EndDate = model.EndDate,
        CarId = model.SelectedCar.Value,
        UserId = ... // current user?
    };
    db.Reservations.Add(reservation);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction(....);`
}
```

And the views will be

`Create.cshtml`

```
@model ReservationVM
...
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate)
    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
}
```

`SelectCar.cshtml`

```
@model ReservationVM
....
<table>
    @foreach(var car in Model.AvailableCars)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@car.Make</td>
            <td>@car.Model</td>
            ....
            <td>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Confirm", "Home", new { StartDate = Model.StartDate, EndDate = Model.EndDate, SelectedCar = car.ID }))
                {
                    <input type="submit" value="Reserve" />
                }
            </td>
        </tr> 
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir!